# How to generate a pdf document using an API?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I use API to generate pdf document. In documentation for this API I have:

```
http://...../view_awb.php?user=nume_utilizator&parola=123456&awb=CGS12345678A
If success, the view_awb.php file will return a PDF document
```

next, I have these code:

```
require "../dbcommon2.php";

$url = "http://webexpress.cargus.ro/custom_print/shipment_import/view_awb.php?user=canai_test&parola=test&awb=TSD21185178T";

$pdf = file_get_contents($url, false);
require_once("../../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($pdf);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

All looks correctly, but when I open pdf file I see only

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj > endobj 4 0 obj > stream  xY[ sÚ8¾ï¯Ðe{UgÙ¹£tèd!KHg/:³ãñ.`Öì7ýõß«Æ6HM;M¤WÞÃ£G¡oýûáHL"ð¥D¦é4Á
```

Where is the problem? How can I generate correctly pdf file ?
I open pdf file sample.pdf by Adobe Reader

Comment: It actually looks like pdf, what do you mean by "I open"? You open it with notepad?

Comment: I open pdf file sample.pdf by Adobe Reader

Comment: Are you setting the content type to `application/pdf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the contents available at http://webexpress.cargus.ro/custom_print/shipment_import/view_awb.php?user=canai_test&parola=test&awb=TSD21185178T is already a .pdf.

You may try (I based on example at http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download):

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");

function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$url = "http://webexpress.cargus.ro/custom_print/shipment_import/view_awb.php?user=canai_test&parola=test&awb=TSD21185178T";

$pdf = get_data($url);

echo $pdf;

?>
```